# How to iterate values from List<String> in setCellValue method of GridBase in spreadsheet controlsfx?

Tags: java, list, javafx, collections, controlsfx

i tried doing this

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add("test1");
values.add("test2");
values.add("test3");
values.add("test4");
values.add("test5");

for(String e : values) {
    for (int column = 0; column < 30; column++){
        mGrid.setCellValue(10, column, e);
    }
}
```

But the only value that is being displayed in the cells is the last value which is "test5".

I also tried displaying the values through the console and it worked fine. Help me plz

Comment: Hey, it is working as expected, what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @DhawalKapil cell 1 = test 1 cell 2 = test 2 something like this but all the cells are just displaying the last item

Comment: ok, why are we iterating from 0 to 30 column, can you upload a snapshot of the sheet that you are expected to be generated from this code. As per the outer for-loop and inner loop, test5 will be written for all the columns 0 to 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate the values and columns together with something like, so instead of:

```
        for(String e : values) {
            for (int column = 0; column < 30; column++){
                mGrid.setCellValue(10, column, e);
            }
        }
```

use something like:

```
        for (int column = 0; column < values.length; column++)
            mGrid.setCellValue(10, column, values.get(column));
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, the for loop with int column is for the spreadsheet table.

Comment: No, this will do just what you said: cell[10, 1] = test1, cell[10, 2] = test2, etc